# How can I create a "Create" view in MVC using a List of objects in the view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to MVC in general but I am trying to figure out the best way to do create a form to create a model that has a list of another object as a property.

Here is my form on my web page:
[Create Recipe Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpfwm.png)

When you click the "Add another step" button it will add another section to the form to enter in the details of the next step.

Below are the models I am using with the annotations removed.

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int yield { get; set; }
    public int preptime { get; set; }
    public int cooktime { get; set; }
    public List<RecipeVariation> variations { get; set; }
    public List<RecipeStep> steps { get; set; }
    public List<RecipeNote> notes { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeStep
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int stepNum { get; set; }
    public string header { get; set; }
    public string bodyText { get; set; }
}
```

My current solution is to pass a FormCollection through to the HttpPost ActionResult Create in my controller, however, the collection is difficult to parse through. Everytime you add a new "RecipeStep" the name is altered so that I do not have the values concatenated when calling Model.header or Model.bodyText. Is there a better way to parse through this information or even pass through the RecipeSteps as a List?

Thank you

Comment: You have to post the code you have done already. Not just the picture what you want

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to take a foreign key receipeId in receipestep model.
Then on create button click in action method in controller take two parameters(Receipe receipe,List receipestep) and pass object to those parameters.
Then save object to database as first insert into Receipe table and then insert into receipestep table and pass Id of Receipe model as foreign key ReceipeId in ReceipeStep model.
Thanks.
Hope you understand